# Highcharts - tooltip using click event doesn't appear all times

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am showing tooltip in Highchart using custom code. The code bellow works fine most of the time, But in some scenarios when the user click outside of the serie (line), then tooltip doesn't appear again.

```
events: {     
           load: function(){
                  this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);                    
                           }
        },
 plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stickyTracking: false,
                events: {
                    click: function(evt) {
                        this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {
                        this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
                    }                       
                }

            }
        }
```

Is there some way to avoid this wrong behaviour?.

How to reproduce the issue:

- click on one point inside of line (chart will show you the tooltip correctly)
- click outside of the area of selection.
- click again on the same point. You will not get the tooltip. (the click event is not fired).

Code is found here: http://jsfiddle.net/rolandomartinezg/cuhvjqcq/ .

UPDATE: Looks like it's a default behaviour from Higchart:
I have created a new example not using any custom code for tooltip (tooltip enabled:false)... and the selection of one point in the serie is working in the same way as the example above.
How to see it:

- Pass the mouse over one point
- Move the mouse out of the point
- Pass the mouse over to the same point again.

RESULT: The point will not be selected again. the only way to get the same point selected is move the mouse to another point and move the mouse back again. See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rolandomartinezg/pnm3bu14/

Comment: Weird behavior indeed. Using version 4.1.5 gives more of an expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/cuhvjqcq/3/

Comment: I think that it is a bug and you can find more information about this issue on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5491

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński the url what you have mention contains a workaround. please add it as answer. this is the workaround:
http://jsfiddle.net/vh2uer6n/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information about this problem on Highcharts github:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5491

On this topic you can find a workaround for your problem, made by Paweł Fus:

```
point: {
   events: {
      mouseOut: function () {
         this.series.chart.pointer.prevKDPoint = null;
      }
   }
}
```

And here you can find an example of a chart with this workaround:
http://jsfiddle.net/vh2uer6n/5/